# How to find the mass of the following solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, water

What is the weight of a 1L of 0.5M solution of  NaCl? Is it the whole solution weight 29.22 grams?

Comment: You might want to reconsider your views on solutions. To begin with, water is also a part of your solution, and it also has weight.

Comment: Please edit your post and add how you would try to solve this question (_i.e._ add your calculation). That helps users to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your 29.22 g is the mass of the NaCl in your solution.

You're missing the mass of the water. This is probably around 1 kg, and if you don't need a very precise result you could just say that the total mass of your solution is about 1000 g + 29.22 g = 1029 g, give or take a couple percent.

If you need a more precise number, the question gets much more difficult. You don't know the exact mass of the water because you don't know the volume of the NaCl in solution. It's not necessarily the same as the volume of 29.22 g of solid NaCl because there are interactions between the water molecules and the Na+ and Cl- ions in solution.

So rather than trying to understand and quantify those intermolecular interactions, it might be easier to check if someone measured it. Googling around, I'm finding a [paper from 1985](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/je00039a015), but it's behind a paywall. It looks like people have measured the density aqueous salt solution very carefully at many temperatures and concentrations, but I can't find a comprehensive, authoritative table with their results. What we get is [this chart at EngineeringToolBox](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/density-aqueous-solution-inorganic-sodium-salt-concentration-d_1957.html) (the 3rd one). Zoom in a little, and you get 1.04 g/cm^3 for 0.5 M NaCl at 20°C. That would make your mass 1.04 kg.

Depending on your standards, 1.04 kg is almost the same as the 1029 g we got using the "stupid" approach above (it's off by only 1%) or it's very different (we thought a ~0.7 M solution should have that mass, not a 0.5 M solution).

If you need better precision, go have a look at [this paper](https://pubs.usgs.gov/bul/1421c/report.pdf). Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

You’d first have to calculate the mass of NaCl in the solution:

moles NaCl = 1*0.5 = 0.5 mol
Therefore mass NaCl = mass/Mr = 0.5/(23+35.5) = 1/117g

The density of water is 1g/cm^3 therefore 1L=1000cm^3

So the mass of the water = density * volume = 1*1000 = 1000g

So the total mass of solution is 1000 + 1/117 = 1000.008547g

Comment: Please notice that this site has the policy that questions should show some own efforts. Therefore, please do not encourage users who did not show these efforts by answering them (until they did).

Comment: Besides, you are doing it wrong anyway.